# typo3 templavoila check current language

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Hi i have 4 languages in my typo. Here is my main configuration for them:

```
#LANGS
config.linkVars=L
config.defaultGetVars.L = 0
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
config.sys_language_uid = 3
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 3
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.sys_language_uid = 2
config.language = ro
config.locale_all = ro_RO
config.htmlTag_langKey = ro
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 1
[global]
```

All works fine.
Im using templavoila and realurl.

In one of templates/modules/flexible content i have typoscript displays field only when its not empty:

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = field_test
10.wrap = info: |
10.if.isTrue.field = field_test
```

Now i'd like to display this field in diferent versions:

like:

```
10.wrap = informationen |
```

for DE language etc.

How may i check here what current language is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using translation labels in TypoScript**

You can use a translation label in TypoScript. For example:

```
{LLL:typo3conf/customlabels.xlf:label.id}
{LLL:EXT:mytemplateext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:label.id}
```

You may want to look at:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/BasicSetupOfALocalizedWebsite/Llxml%28locallang-xml%29InPluginsAndTyposcript/Index.html

> llXML files are XML files containing labels that the system can fetch in a localized version if a language pack is installed. If you want to retrieve values from llXML files in TypoScript you can do it like this:

```
page.20 = TEXT page.20.stdWrap.data =
LLL:EXT:indexed_search/pi/locallang.xml:submit_button_label
```

And see also:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Internationalization/Introduction/Index.html
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/Localization/Locallang-xml%28llxml%29Files/Index.html

**TypoScript variables**

You can extend your language configuration with your own settings. For example:

```
#LANGS
config.linkVars=L
config.defaultGetVars.L = 0
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
myLanguageLabels {
    info = info
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
config.sys_language_uid = 3
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
myLanguageLabels {
    info = info 2
}
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 3
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.sys_language_uid = 2
config.language = ro
config.locale_all = ro_RO
config.htmlTag_langKey = ro
myLanguageLabels {
    info = info 3
}
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 2
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.lang = 1
myLanguageLabels {
    info = info 3
}
[global]
```

And then just point out to the variable you want to use:

```
10.wrap = {$myLanguageLabels.info}: |
```

Comment: Yes, it is good option. But if i have for example 1000 labels then its gonna be mess.. Im looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: I have expanded my answer :)